# Why alert dialog delete the wrong item in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a problem in my SwiftUI project, and  I am trying to use alert dialog to delete an item in a list, but when use the  .alert, wrong item gets deleted. I am still do not know what I missed?

Here is my code:

```
struct CustomView: View {
    @State private var selectedUsers: CustomModel?
    @State var users: [CustomModel]
    @State private var selectDelete = false
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false, content: {  
            VStack(content: {
                ForEach(users){ user in
                    CustomRowView(user: user)
                        .contextMenu {
                            Button(action: {
                                self.delete(item: data)
                            }) {
                                Text("remove") 
                            }
                        }
                        .onTapGesture {
                            selectedUsers = user
                        }
                        .alert(isPresented: $selectDelete) {
                            Alert(title: Text("title"),
                                message: Text("message"),
                                primaryButton: .destructive(Text("Delete")) {
                                    self.delete(item: user)
                                },
                                secondaryButton: .cancel()
                            )
                        }
                        .onDelete { (indexSet) in
                            self.users.remove(atOffsets: indexSet)
                        }
                }
            })
        })
    }

    private func delete(item user: CustomModel) {
        if let index = users.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == user.id }) {
            users.remove(at: index)
        }
    }
}
```

**model:**

```
struct CustomModel: Identifiable{
var id = UUID().uuidString
var name: String
}

var users = [

CustomModel(name: "david"),
CustomModel(name: "marry"),
CustomModel(name: "henry"),
CustomModel(name: "nadi"), ]
```

Comment: You're setting `selectedUser` to `user` but then deleting `user`  you might try removing `.first.(where: { $0 == user } )`. I also just noticed you're not using your created function.

Comment: @xTwisteDx, tnx so much for ur comment, what u reccommned

Comment: Which part fixes it?

Comment: @xTwisteDx, it is work very well without alert dialog, if I use with alert, it is throw this error, and delete unselected item, I do not know why

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 2 problems in your code that are creating the unexpected behaviour:

1. When you iterate through the user with `ForEach`, you are attaching one `.alert()` modifier to each single instance. This means, when `selectDelete` is set to `true`, **all** of the instances try to show an alert, but only one will. Which one? Who knows, but that instance will be deleted.
2. You have a nice `selectedUsers` variable that changes when you tap on it. But you are deleting the `user`, not `selectedUser`.

How you can fix your code to work with `.alert()` in 3 steps:

- if you don't need to perform any task with the tap gesture, just delete it and change the `selectedUser` in your context menu:

```
.contextMenu {
    Button(action: {

    selectedUsers = user    // Change here then delete

    self.delete(item: data)
}) {
    Text("remove") }}

    // Forget about it...
    //.onTapGesture {
    //    selectedUsers = user
    //}
```

- attach your alert to the top-most level of your view (at the bottom):

```
ScrollView {
    ...
}
.alert(isPresented: $selectDelete) {
    ...
}
```

- delete `selectedUser`, not `user`:

```
self.delete(item: selectedUser)
```

Comment: tnx so much for ur answer, but I am not understand it, can u update ur answer according to question, I confused

Comment: @HumbleDeveloper01: Let me try to answer it in this comment. 1) You have an alert that is being repeated for each user, this is not good. 2) You are deleting the `user`, but you need to delete the `selectedUser`. 3) Ensure the `selectedUser` is set when you hit the context menu.

Comment: Understand now tnx so much